# Condition to Run Macro based on Cell Value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to come up with an IF statement that will trigger my macro to run based on a specific value in one cell. My Spreadsheet has many tabs. This is for a forecasting template.

Here is what I have come up with but I am running out of ideas..

```
function Sum_Calcs() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Integrity Check'), true);
   spreadsheet.getRange(K20).getValue(getActiveRange(), true);

if(activeRange === "1") {
}
```

*//My Script is then located beneath//*

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify. Please correct me if I am wrong. You have a Spreadsheet, one sheet is called "Integrity Check", Cell "K20" on that sheet is the critical cell. When someone types something in the spreadsheet, you want to check whether the entry made in Cell K20? If it was, then you want to check the value of Cell K20; if "K20" = 1, then do such and such; if K20 <> = 1, then do nothing/something else.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to

- implement an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) function to re-evaluate the if statement each time the value in "K20" was changed (please note that it will work automatically only if the value has been changed manually, by a human)
- A second function (macro) that will be called within the `if` statement if your condition is fulfilled

Based on your code snippet above there some things you need to change:

1. When you use the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) to retrieve the value of a cell - do not specify any parameter within the brackets `()` of the method. Instead, assign the return value of this method to a variable
2. If you want to retrieve a cell value (or perform any other operation) in a certain sheet, use [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getSheetByName(String)) instead of `setActiveSheet`
3. To compare within an `if` statement the actual value against an integer (number) use `if(activeRange == 1)`
4. Note that when getting a range in A1 notation you need to use quotes ("")

Sample code based on your situation:

```
function myForecastMacro(){
  // specify here what shall happen if your "if" statement is fulfilled

function onEdit() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Integrity Check');
   var activeRange=sheet.getRange("K20").getValue();
   if(activeRange == 1) {
     myForecastMacro();
  }
}
```